# NullPointerException when Implementing Custom Action Bar

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar

I'm new to android and facing a NullPointerException when trying to implement a custom Action toolbar.

I have a project where I'm trying to add a back button and a custom title on the 2nd activity.
The back button is expected to take it to the 1st activity.

I've made the following changes -

AndroidManifest.xml -

```
<activity
            android:name=".views.SecondActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".views.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

SecondActivity.kt -

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)

        /* I see the null pointer exception here below - */
        supportActionBar!!.title = "Custom text" 
        supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

    }
```

This error appears when trying to incorporate the back button and custom text in one of my existing projects.

When I tried to test just this functionality on a new separate Android Studio project, I was able to see the action button work properly.
So I know the above code is supposed to work.

The only difference in the project where I get the error, is that I have all the activities inside a subfolder called "views".

I don't want to believe that keeping activities in a subfolder could cause the NullPointerException.
Can you tell me what else I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try this -->

```
 var mActionBarToolbar = findViewById<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>(R.id.toolbartable);
    setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
    // add back arrow to toolbar
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null){
        getSupportActionBar()?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar()?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar()?.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_left_black_24dp);

      //for setting title
        getSupportActionBar()?.setTitle((Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFFFFF\">" + getString(R.string.yourname) + "</font>")));

    }
```

Comment: Thanks.
Can you please explain what is in your - R.id.toolbartable file?
From my understanding, it can be done without any additional drawable/layout file

Comment: you must have toolbar in layout to get access of `getSupportActionBar` ...thats why it was showing null...note:- R.id.toolbartable ==> it is not a file ...

Comment: Oh so this is like having a new NoActionBar theme and setting up a custom bar.
That makes sense.
But the one I was talking about doesn't need any custom styles / toolbars / vectors